# Ruby '{x}' block works, but 'do |x|' block does not?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a method and for some reason it's throwing an error whenever I run an `each` block like this:

```
array.each do |i|
something_on_i
end
```

But, it's not throwing an error when I do the same thing like this:

```
array.each {|i| something_on_i}
```

Why?  I thought the two were identical.

Here's the full code:

Working:

```
def factor(num)
    i=2
    factors=[1]
    while i<=num
        if (num % i == 0)
          factors << i
        end
     i+=1
    end
    return factors
end

def Division(num1,num2)
  facs1=factor(num1)
  facs2=factor(num2)
  common=[]

  ***facs2.each {|i| common << i if facs1.include?i}***

  return common.max

end

# keep this function call here 
# to see how to enter arguments in Ruby scroll down   
Division(STDIN.gets)
```

Not working:

```
def factor(num)
    i=2
    factors=[1]
    while i<=num
        if (num % i == 0)
          factors << i
        end
     i+=1
    end
    return factors
end

def Division(num1,num2)
  facs1=factor(num1)
  facs2=factor(num2)
  common=[]

  ***facs2.each do |i| 
    if facs1.include?(i)       
    common << i
    end
   end***

  return common.max

end

# keep this function call here 
# to see how to enter arguments in Ruby scroll down   
Division(STDIN.gets)
```

The error I get is:

```
(eval):334: (eval):334: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):323: syntax error, unexpected kDO_COND, expecting kEND
  facs2.each do |i|
               ^
(eval):324: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
(eval):334: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
```

Comment: Your code works for me (omitting the two ***'s of course).

Comment: @LoganSerman  Interesting.. are you running locally? It failed for me on both Coderbyte and Repl.it (both browser based), so I just assumed it was bad. any idea what's going on?

Comment: Yup I just pasted it directly into IRB and it works.

Comment: Could it be that your indentation has something to do with it? Try indenting the two lines `if facs1.include?(i)` and `common << i`. I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, it works in irb for me too. Strange that Coderbyte and repl.it both throw this error but irb does not.  I suppose this is just a bug with repl.it and Coderbyte

Comment: It also works to rewrite the `while` as an `each` or to move the `factor` definition after `Division`. Something is seriously wrong with those sites' evals.

Comment: I think it is the problem with Ruby 1.8.7. Both, Coderbyte and Repl.it, runs Ruby 1.8.7. ps. You need 2x gets

Comment: Ruby doesn't care about indentation, unlike Python which uses indentation to denote blocks. `do`/`end` and `{`/`}` denote blocks in Ruby.

Comment: @tomtom I also feel obliged to point out that you can reduce your whole expression to simply `(facs1 & facs2).max` rather than bothering with blocks or `<<` at all.

Comment: @simonwo That's a great suggestion. I didn't know you could throw the "&" in between two arrays and Ruby would pull out the max shared by both. Very cool. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the Greatest Common Divisor? `12.gcd(30) #=>6`

Comment: @steenslag thanks for that, I didn't know that method existed.  I think the point of the CoderByte challenge was to write a GCD method yourself, but in the future I'll definitely keep that .gcd() method in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the great help in the comments from everyone, it appears this is just an issue with  Coderbyte and Repl.it, rather than an issue with the code itself.  The code runs just fine in irb.  @Darek Nedza pointed out that Coderbyte and Repl.it are only running Ruby 1.8.7, which is likely the problem.

**Solution:**
For strange errors on Repl.it or Coderbyte, just double check in irb